# Multiple if statements in mit-scheme

Tags: if-statement, scheme, mit-scheme

I'm trying to create multiple nested if statements in mit-scheme with a similar structure as:

```
(if (null? (x))
L
    (if (< (x) (y))
        .. do stuff .. )
    (if (< (y) (z))
        .. do stuff .. )
)
```

However, when I compile it, it gives me:

```
Ill-formed special form: (if (null? ...) l (if ... ... ...) (if ... ... ...))
```

Does anyone know what's causing this? I'm essentially trying to go: if this condition is true, check if these two conditions are also true and perform an action accordingly.

I'm compiling with:

`mit-scheme --quiet --load program.scm`

Comment: `if` takes precisely three arguments: a test, a then-clause, and an else-clause. Your question is not really clear enough to tell you what you meant to write, but it is clear you cannot write `(if t l (if ...) (if ...))`. Decide whether you mean each sub-test to be part of the `then` or `else`, and place them accordingly.

Comment: Also, check if a `cond` would be more appropriate for your use case. It allows testing for multiple conditions, not just if/else.